# Computing the Moments of a Function with Complex Analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Find the moments of $f(x) = \exp(-x^{1/4})\sin(x^{1/4})$

So the integral is (for $n=0,1,2...$)

$$\int_0^\infty x^n \exp(-x^{1/4})\sin(x^{1/4}) \space dx $$

Doing a change of variables $(x=y^4)$ gets us

$$\Im\left[\int_0^\infty 4y^{4n+3}e^{(-1+i)y} \space dy\right] $$

Now I'm tempted to do another change of variables and letting $z=(-1+i)y$, but the jump to complex analysis is losing me here. What is the new region I'm integrating on with this substitution? How does the Complex Analysis come into play?

Comment: Corrected a mistake. Added $\Im[]$

Comment: I have seen a similar computation on Reed & Simon, first volume: https://books.google.es/books?id=rpFTTjxOYpsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA321#v=onepage&q&f=false 

Example 1: in the last line, they essentially do the change of variable $t'=(t+i\lambda/\sqrt{2\alpha})$, and then refer to $t'$ simply as $t$. Justification for this operation is provided in the subsequent page (unfortunately not in the preview, at least for me). I hope that this may help you.

Comment: Strange. I got $0$ for any integer $n\quad$ $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-\sqrt[4]{x}} x^n \sin \left(\sqrt[4]{x}\right) \, dx=-\frac{\sin (\pi  n)}{4^n (4 n+3)!}$

Comment: @Raffaele: it is correct, this is a famous instance of the moment problem, it has already been mentioned on MSE for sure, I just need some time to find *where*.

Comment: Related: https://books.google.it/books?id=uTtDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=moment+zero+sin+x%5E1/4&source=bl&ots=F4ovGXa0zW&sig=AYzdZJ6QZ_M9O2RqWoKhM8STV-I&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0lOKblM_VAhVjD8AKHdduCMQQ6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=moment%20zero%20sin%20x%5E1%2F4&f=false

Comment: And this MO thread, too: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31295/let-a-function-f-have-all-moments-zero-what-conditions-force-f-to-be-identicall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\eta=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}=e^{-\pi i/4}\in S^1$. The given integral is

$$ \text{Im}\int_{0}^{+\infty} 4y^{4n+3}e^{-\sqrt{2}\eta y}\,dy \stackrel{y\mapsto\frac{z}{\eta\sqrt{2}}}{=}\frac{1}{4^n}\text{Im}\int_{0}^{(1+i)\infty}z^{4n+3}e^{-z}\,dz\tag{1}$$
or:
$$ \frac{1}{4^n}\text{Im}\lim_{R\to +\infty}\left[\int_{0}^{R}z^{4n+3}e^{-z}\,dz+\int_{R}^{R(1+i)}z^{4n+3}e^{-z}\,dz\right]\tag{2}$$
where $\int_{0}^{R}z^{4n+3}e^{-z}\,dz$ is real and $\int_{R}^{R(1+i)}z^{4n+3}e^{-z}\,dz$ is bounded by:
$$\left|\int_{R}^{R(1+i)}z^{4n+3}e^{-z}\,dz\right|\leq R e^{-R}\left(R\sqrt{2}\right)^{4n+3}\tag{3}$$
which goes to zero as $R\to +\infty$. It follows that the original integral equals zero as well.

As mentioned in the comments, this is a famous integral: have a look at [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31295/let-a-function-f-have-all-moments-zero-what-conditions-force-f-to-be-identicall).